# Magento 2: How to add a credit card logo/image before amazon pay button on the checkout page?

Tags: user-interface, knockout.js, magento2, amazon-pay, magento-layout-xml

I'm trying to add a a credit card logo/image before Amazon Pay button  on the checkout page. Please guide me on how do I go about achieving this? [screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0EHs.png)

Comment: I think it is not possible because Amazon Pay is a 'checkout method', not a 'payment method'. So in contrast to a usual payment method, it provides the user the possibility to select an address that is stored within his Amazon account, so the user doesn't need to enter this information manually on the regular checkout page.

Comment: Thank you Jinesh. I got your point about Amazon Pay being a checkout method. I would only want it moved down after the shipping address, right before the Shipping Methds part. Magento Devdoc has some information on doing this, however it isn't very clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply overriding the .phtml file that displays Amazon Pay button. Look for the template file somewhere under Vendor/Amazon/Payments directory where you will find checkout-button.html.